# ViTest: failing while working with separate test file for each module

Tags: node.js, testing, supertest, vitest

I am writing the `automated-tests` for multi-module application for testing.

When I am create a different test file for each module, `vitest` is running only that file that I was working on and all the other tests are getting failed. But, if I write all the tests in a single file then every test works like a charm.

I noticed that for each file the database is connecting again.

Screenshot of separate test files
[image: Screenshot of separate test files]

Screenshot of single test file for all the modules
[image: Screenshot of single test file for all the modules]

I have already cleared the database before running each test to avoid any data-duplicacy issue.

How to fix this...?